# WSL (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS) で Spresense への「1.5.バイナリイメージのロード」ができません

Tags: spresense, wsl

Windows Subsystem for Linux (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS) で Spresense への「1.5.バイナリイメージのロード」ができません．

[Spresense公式サイトのセットアップ手順](https://developer.sony.com/ja/develop/spresense/developer-tools/get-started-using-nuttx/set-up-the-nuttx-environment) を参考に，

1. SpresenseをUSB経由でPCに接続
2. Windowsデバイスマネージャー側で認識確認（Silicon Labs CP210x USB to UART Bridge(COM7)）
3. Windows Subsystem for Linux（Ubuntu 18.04 LTS）にて「dmesg | grep "cp21.*attached"」コマンドを実行

したところ，デバイスが見えません．他のPCでも同様に試しましたが，結果は変わりませんでした．また予備のボードでも試しましたが．Windowsデバイスマネージャー側で認識できていることから，ボードは壊れていないと考えており，ソフト側の問題と思っております．

また，Windows環境（MSYS2 MSYS）でも同様に試してみましたが，

1. SpresenseをUSB経由でPCに接続
2. Windowsデバイスマネージャー側で認識確認（Silicon Labs CP210x USB to UART Bridge(COM7)）
3. MYSY2 MSYSにて `tools/flash.sh -c /dev/ttyUSB7 nuttx.spk` を実行

   ```
   could not open port 'C:/msys64/dev/ttyUSB7': 　　
   FileNotFoundError(2, '▒w▒肳▒ꂽ▒t▒@▒C▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒܂▒▒▒B', None, 2)
   Cannot open port : C:/msys64/dev/ttyUSB7
   ```

となり，こちらも上手くいきません．

上記の通り，デバイスが認識できない原因が分からず困っています．
何方かお力添えいただけますと幸いです．
宜しくお願いいたします．

Comment: 一つ確認させていただきますが、USB コードは本体側につないでいますか❓

Answer (score 0):

Windows Subsystem for Linux(以下WSL)の場合、ネイティブのUbuntuと同様の方法ではデバイスを検索できません。
WSL上でのシリアルポートは、COMポートの番号と対応付けられており、

```
 COMX = /dev/ttySX
```

と置き換えていただければシリアルポートを使用できます。

Windows上でポートが `COM7` の場合、WSLでは

```
 /dev/ttyS7
```

になりますので、

```
$ tools/flash.sh -c /dev/ttyS7 nuttx.spk
```

でロードすることができます。

また、MSYS2上ではCOMポート番号がそのまま利用でき、下記のコマンドでロードできます。

```
$ tools/flash.sh -c COM7 nuttx.spk
```

今後ともSPRESENSEをどうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

SPRESENSEサポートチーム